# Where is the corresponding device folder for aosp x86_64 lunch combo?

Tags: android, android-source, custom-rom, android-rom

I have successfully built the aosp_x86_64 from lunch combo.

Now I want to customize the build by adding overlay folder. But I couldn't find it's corresponding device tree folder. Please let me know the location of the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I struggled with this for a couple of days and finally found aosp_x86_64.mk in $ANDROID_SOURCE/build/target/product folder.

I opened the file and added DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS attribute in it and set it to a path I liked. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It is  /device/generic/car/common/product/ . You can add the overlay folder inside this path .

Check files under these for details :
http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/device/generic/car/common/product/